# Add custom element criteria attribute without a field type?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

Is a custom field type and making use of `modifyElementsQuery` the only way to add my own `craft.entries` element criteria model attribute to modify the elements query?

What if I do not want to add a new field to each entry type I want to use my  attribute with? The field would be a hidden pseudo field anyways, as I'm **only working with other fields' data**.

My current solution is passing the element criteria model with all other params set to `craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery()` using a template variable. It works, yes, but I would really like to avoid this (pagination not possible and some other disadvantages).

Comment: Have you thought about using a template hook? If you think that might be a viable solution, I can write up an official answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Lindsey, but I need this to be a bit more flexible than a template hook would make this for the user of the plugin.

Comment: Makes sense... and that's exactly why I didn't spend time writing a full answer already. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, yes, the only way to modify an element query (when it’s not your own element type) is to do it with a custom field type, from its [modifyElementsQuery()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/fieldtypes/IFieldType#modifyElementsQuery-detail) function.

**UPDATE**

As of Craft 2.5, plugins can listen for the [elements.onBeforeBuildElementsQuery](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBeforeBuildElementsQuery) and [elements.onBuildElementsQuery](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBuildElementsQuery) events to make changes to the query (or prevent it from getting executed).

```php
craft()->on('elements.buildElementsQuery', function(Event $event) {
    /** @var ElementCriteriaModel $criteria */
    $criteria = $event->params['criteria'];

    /** @var DbCommand $query */
    $query = $event->params['query'];

    if ($criteria->myCustomParamName) {
        $query->andWhere( //...
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your suggested `buildElementsQuery` event, but when I use `$criteria->myCustomParamName` it's not passing `myCustomParamName` to my plugin and I'm getting an error in the logfiles `Property "Craft\ElementCriteriaModel.myCustomParamName" is not defined.` I'm trying to use a custom parameter from the elementCriteria in my templates. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Christiaan What version of Craft are you running?

Comment: @Brandon I'm using Craft 2.5.2761